# Steam opens and then just closes

Tags: 20.04, steam

Title. (Version: 20.04.2 LTS) Here is what the console says.

```
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
Steam client's requirements are satisfied
WARNING: Using default/fallback debugger launch
/home/brokenflaregun/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam -nominidumps -nobreakpad
[2021-07-02 13:27:27] Startup - updater built Jun  8 2021 22:23:36
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  45
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
Serial number of failed request:  46
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2021-07-02 13:27:27] Failed to load cached hosts file (File 'update_hosts_cached.vdf' not found), using defaults
[2021-07-02 13:27:27] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal
[2021-07-02 13:27:27] 1. http://media.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'baked in'
[2021-07-02 13:27:27] Checking for update on startup
[2021-07-02 13:27:27] Checking for available updates...
[2021-07-02 13:27:27] Downloading manifest: http://media.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
[2021-07-02 13:27:27] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1623193086, installed version 1623193086, existing pending version 0
[2021-07-02 13:27:27] Nothing to do
[2021-07-02 13:27:27] Verifying installation...
[2021-07-02 13:27:27] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2021-07-02 13:27:27] Verification complete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the same problem before. I rollback my nvidia driver to v450 and Steam came back to work.

So, the most easy way to do it is opening the 'Software & Update' find the 'Additional Drivers' tab and then choose an old driver version.